# Wordpress REST Api: How to serve multiple concurrently Calls?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I am developing a WordPress plugin and I am running into performance issues when it comes to working with the REST API.
I registered a route as follows (code inside a class):

```
public function __construct()
{
    add_action('rest_api_init', array($this, 'register_rest_load'));
    add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_scripts'));
}

public function register_rest_load()
{
    //Versioned namespace 
    $namespace = 'scs/v1';

    // Register the route
    register_rest_route($namespace, '/load/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods'   => WP_REST_Server::ALLMETHODS,
        'callback'  => array($this,'loadProfile'),
        'args' => array()
    ));
}
```

The Function "loadProfile" walks through an loading script that returns xhr messages to the frontend ajax while it is gathering data from a bunch of other databases.
As this is working perfectly I will not include it here.
The Problem I am facing here is that if I make multiple ajax call to

"my-url.de/wp-json/scs/v1/load/[any_int_here]"

at the same time, it is only serving 1 ajax call per time.
But it happens so that the "loadProfile" function is taking up 3 minutes to run.
As I changed from my own hardcoded and directly called ajax(6 simultaneously calls possible) to the more secure WordPress REST(only 1 call), I lost my performance. I tried the WordPress ajax too but the same there ... only 1 serving.

Is there any way I messed up creating the route and endpoint?
Can I modify my route and endpoint towards multiple servings per client?
Or should I just go back to manual ajax ?

Thanks in before.
If I am missing any informations please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's PHP you can't do multi-threading. You will not be able to serve multiple calls at same time to same client.

However I did some ugly hack in the past to overcome this, you can create multiple subdomains pointing to same server, with same document root.

Ex:

```
    http://api1.test.com   \
    http://api2.test.com    - /var/www/htdocs/wp-api
    // .....               /
    http://apiN.test.com  /
```

This way you can make as may asynchronous requests as you wish (of course each request to different subdomain), or at least how many your server can handle.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer :) Thats some nice workaround there ^^